# Pass variables in window.open js with XSLT

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have a XSLT style sheet that renders the html page. The page has a table with a list of members. I am trying to add a link to each member in the table that will popup a new window and in that new window I want to access member information that was clicked. I tried to google but could not find a single solution that works.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open('/Provider/MemberEvents.aspx?itemId=<xsl:value-of select="MemberNumber"></xsl:value-of>')">Member Events</a>
```

"Member Events" is the link that shows for each member and when the user clicks on that link i want to pass the Member Number to the popup window. The above code has incorrect syntax and gives the following error:

Character '<', hexadecimal value 0x3c is illegal in XML attribute values.

Comment: I believe you should be using the `xsl:attribute` tag to set the attribute there.

Comment: I think i know what you are saying but i dont want to display the link as member number, i want to pass in the member information in the link to the pop up window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Daniel and @Jeff for your answers.

The following solution worked:

```
 <a href="javascript: void(0)"
       onclick="window.open('/Provider/MemberEvents.aspx?id={Coverages/Coverage[1]/MemberNumber}', 
      'Member Events', 
      'width=1120, height=900'); 
       return false;">Member Events</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an [AVT (attribute value template)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates)...

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open('/Provider/MemberEvents.aspx?itemId={MemberNumber}')">Member Events</a>
```

Comment: This is what i get in the new tab link:
/Provider/MemberEvents.aspx?itemId=

No value for MemberNumber

Comment: @ankk - Look at what the context is when you're outputting the `a`. Does that context have a child `MemberNumber` element? Is it in a namespace? You'll need to update the path. If it's not obvious, you'll have to provide more info (sample input and xslt that reproduces the issue).